# Changing connection string in run time

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

Hi I'm writing a WinForm application and I want to my user to select server and database when he runs application. So I have this code:

```
StringBuilder Con = new StringBuilder("Data Source=");
Con.Append(textBox1.Text);
Con.Append(";Initial Catalog=");
//Con.Append(";AttachDbFilename=");
Con.Append(textBox2.Text);
Con.Append(";Integrated Security=true;");
string str = Con.ToString();
Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
//the full name of the connection string can be found in the app.config file
// in the "name" attribute of the connection string
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString = str;
//Save to file
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

//force changes to take effect so that we can start using
//this new connection string immediately
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.Name);
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WF_AbsPres.Properties.Settings.Default.con))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TypeofUseName", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TypeofUse_code";
}
```

My app.config file is like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con"
        connectionString=""
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And clearly I have `con` in my `settings` file with initial value of null.

When I run the code it says you have to give initial value to connection string.  What's wrong ? Am I missing something? (I put comboBox just to test the connection)

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Is str variable holding the necessary connection string value? At which line You are getting that error? When You try to save config file or elsewhere?